# Java: Method returns Class<T> (where <T extends BaseType>). Returning subclass class causes type mismatch error

Tags: java, generics

Long time reader, first time caller (on this board anyway).

Envision the following:

```
 public class BaseClass{ }

 public class C1 extends BaseClass { }

 public class C2 extends BaseClass { }
```

Now, I have a method:

```
private static <T extends BaseClass> Class<T> getBaseClassType(boolean b) {
    if (b) {
        return C1.class;
    } else {
        return C2.class;
    }
}
```

I would think this is valid since both `C1.class` `C2.class` fulfill the type declaration `<T extends BaseClass>`.
However, the 'return' statements are tagged with "Type mismatch: cannot convert from `Class<C1>` to `Class<T>`".

Why is that? Can the method above be re-expressed in a manner to not require casts?

I am able to cast the returned values like this:

```
private static <T extends BaseClass> Class<T> getBaseClassType(boolean b) {
    if (b) {
        return (Class<T>) C1.class;
    } else {
        return (Class<T>) C2.class;
    }
}
```

...but this generates warnings "Type safety: Unchecked cast from Class to Class" (which, of course, can be suppressed). I'm confused as to why this is necessary since `C1` (or `C2`) extends `BaseClass`.

What's the "right" way to do this to make the editor/compiler happy?

*thanks!*

Comment: Consider making it `static Class<? extends BaseClass> getBaseClassType(...)`.

Comment: Yes.. that worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the solution is to remove the explicit type and substitute an unknown type specification:

```
private static Class<? extends BaseClass> getBaseClassType(boolean b) {
    if (b) {
        return (Class<T>) C1.class;
    } else {
        return (Class<T>) C2.class;
    }
}
```

I found this after searching around some of the 'related' answers.

Comment: There is no `T` declared here.

Answer (score 1):

You have to adjust the class return type as shown below.

```
private static Class<? extends BaseClass> getBaseClassType(boolean b) {
    if (b) {
        return  C1.class;
    } else {
        return C2.class;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because copy & paste of an other answer. Doesn't add anything useful, so it's just noise.

Comment: Nope...its not copy paste. I tried in editor and by the time I posted...@fluffy already answered. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Even if someone else posted the same answer as you before - it still doesn't add anything.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn: The other answer contains a syntax error. This doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that a cast is a runtime check and compile time its not known what would be type of T that why its raising warning to check the type of class before cast for safer side.

Use @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") to suppress warning -

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Method signature

or add unknown type as

private static Class<? extends BaseClass> getBaseClassType(boolean b)

Comment: No need to use `@SuppressWarnings` here. Look at the other answers to see how it can be done. Note: `Class<Foo>` means `Foo.class`, nothing else.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned the same in my comment too. Any of the option can be used.

Comment: A variable of type `Class<BaseClass>` should only ever hold `BaseClass.class` or `null`. Never `C1.class`.

Comment: It would be nice to provide solution to the needy rather getting into the argument. I really did not understand what are trying to prove by commenting here and there.

Comment: Who is "needy"? Op has it's answer. Sprinkling `@SuppressWarnings` is bad style.

Comment: Running fine for me, not sure where  exactly you want to take this discussion. 
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getBaseClassType(true));
    }

    private static Class<? extends BaseClass> getBaseClassType(boolean b) {
        if (b) {
            return  C1.class;
        } else {
            return  C2.class;
        }
    }